# Selenium & a constantly changing front end

Tags: selenium

I'm running Selenium tests.
The tests break frequently due to DOM changes, so I end up having to go into the code and change selectors.

Does anyone else run into the same problem?
What have you done to mitigate this headache (aside from removing magic strings, using variables and implementing programming patterns to testing code)?

Comment: Which language is your site written in? There are several frameworks written on top of Selenium which can simplify your test cases and make them less brittle. Also, are you utilising PageObject?

Answer (score 0):

heh) I use following solution in my current project:

I contain all the locators in  `selenium-config.properties` file:

[image]

In my BaseSeleniumTest.java I've got the following:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
....
public class BaseSeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestBase {
    static WebDriver driver;

 @Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
//usage example of loading value by key from .properties file
        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));
    }

......
......
public String propertyKeysLoader(String key) throws IOException {
        Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("selenium-config.properties");
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props2 = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props2.setProperties(props);
        return (String)props.get(key)          ;
    }


}
```

So If DOM changes- you simply change your locators in .properties file - and that's it.
Hope it helps you.