# How to start a selenium test in Jenkins (as hub) with an external server as node?

Tags: selenium, grid

I got a (hopefully) little problem:

I'm using Jenkins for building my projects. This works very well, but I also want to use it to test my webprojects.

Jenkins is running on a debian-Server and a Windows-Machine proives the Selenium-Server.

I install the Jenkins Selenium Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin), so Jenkins can run as a hub. My Windows machine is registered as an Selenium-Node to the "Jenkins-Hub". Jenkins shows me the registered Remote Controls in the "Selenium Grid"-Menu. I think they are ready to use.

And here first my question: How do I use the Remote Controls?

I imagine that I tell my projects through the ANT-Build.xml where are the TestSuits and where the result has to be placed. But i found no Syntax for this way of solution. Maybe this is the wrong way?

Best regards Thomas

Answer (score 4):

well, I use selenium web driver+ java + hudson for CI and SVN.
Also I've got a remote machine with 192.168.4.52 IP with XP, JDK and selenium stanalone server  running on it.
So settings be like:
1) Hudson:
[image]

and in your BaseSeleniumTest.java you add somthing like:

```
....
 @BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

          DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();


        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    }
    @Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeFirefox(){
        driver.quit();
    }
```

where in string

```
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

you write the IP address of your remote machine.

BaseSeleniumTest.java - basic class in your selenium project where I describe all basic methods: `isElementPresent(By locator),fluentWait(By locator),isElementVisible(By locator), @Before, @BeforeClass, @AfterCLass, @After`  annotations. Other classes includes only tests covering different forms. And they inherit all methods from BaseSeleniumTest:
[image]

*And how to I tell Jenkins that there is a test-script (BaseSeleniumTest.java), which Jenkins has to run?* 
The matter is that I use maven - as build manager (see hudson settings above) and Tortoise SVN. I create repository, commit in repository my project. Get link, paste it in hudson. And as hudson knows that maven used to build the project (with clean test option). You press Build project - hudson makes: checkout from repository, build the project i.e. run the tests and print results.

Hope it be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for these informations!

I have two questions left:

Where do I put the "BaseSeleniumTest.java"?
And how to I tell Jenkins that there is a test-script (BaseSeleniumTest.java), which Jenkins has to run?

Comment: edited my post. In other words hudson makes maven to build the project in accordance with the settings.

Comment: Witch class do you import for the "propertyKeysLoader(String)"-method? Java coud not find this method :(

Comment: Okay, google helped me in this case ... after a couple of minutes: Got the method from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040185/selenium-a-constantly-changing-front-end and the needed Jar-File vom here: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils (springframework-5.1.0-M1.jar)

Comment: it is my own method:
    public String propertyKeysLoader(String key) throws IOException {
        Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("selenium-config.properties");
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props2 = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props2.setProperties(props);
        return (String)props.get(key)          ;
    }

Comment: I splitted my task because it will not run... So currently I try to run an JUnit4-Selenium-Test on my Jenkins-Machine with a selenium-node as an external server. Like in the past, the Jenkins-Machine knows the node, this is working. When I try to start an test I get the error "Could not start Selenium session: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session The server retunred an error".
So, I think this is a problem of my Test-Java-Class. Could you give me the complete Test-Code for a simple-Test on google.com? This would be great.

Comment: Nevermind, I got a solution for this problem from this site: http://qtp-help.blogspot.de/2011/04/selenium-grid-with-junit.html (demo1.java)